# How get the error in entitiesWithErrors in Breeze

Tags: javascript, breeze

I'm new with breeze, and now when I call savechanges() I get an error:

[image]

Anyone can help me to see what or how I can see what is my problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you not have a validation check in there that it's failing? I'm assuming that's what it means when it says "Error: Validation error". http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/ValidationError.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examine the object passed to your .fail handler.  It will have a property called "entityErrors" when a server-side validation error occurs during saveChanges.

Example:

```
entityManager.saveChanges()
    .then(... do something ...)
    .fail(function(reason) {
        console.log(reason.entityErrors);
    });
```

[image: entityErrors property]

If things are wired up correctly breeze will automatically stuff these errors in your object's validationErrors collection.  You can access them like this:

```
var errors = entity.entityAspect.getValidationErrors();
```